# Cannot Apply the Parent DIV style to the Innner child DIV HTML element

Tags: css, html, styles

I have parent DIV element for which there is an inline style specified with `background:#efefef;`. Then I copied and inserted another DIV element inside the above DIV element. But the background color is not affecting the Child DIV. I want the same background color to the child DIV also to have a wrapped up view.

My HTML code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/aC5P3/2/

Thanks :)-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `float: left;` from the child css.

**OR**

Give apply `float: left;` to parent.